# Why does my macbook shut off for no reason?

Tags: macbook

I've had my Macbook laptop for almost four years now. A few months ago it started having a huge noise with the fan, so I bought one and replaced it recently. I thought this would fix the large jumps in CPU usage and fan speeds (5-6k rpm) just when I'm watching a YouTube video.

But, of course this didn't fix it. Now, it still has same symptoms as before: when I even watch a show the fan is at 6krpm, processor is at like 90% usage. But, to make things even better, now the laptop is just shutting off when the rpm/processor gets cranked up. This happens a lot now, because I'll have Photoshop, Lastfm, Chrome, and TextWrangler open and then all of a sudden it's just too much.

I'm using Chrome. This shouldn't be happening.

Is my processor bad? Did I install the fan wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You may have installed the fan wrong. These are pretty classic symptoms of **overheating**. Give the laptop a bit of a clean, especially around the airflows, and make sure the fans are working right.

On a side note, don't worry about flash being slow. It's slow and heavy for all of us.

Answer (score 1):

Your computer is probably overheating. My Macbook gets very hot on the bottom, with the fan racing along at 6000rpm but it doesn't switch off. I have a temperature program that claims the CPU gets up to 80C, but everything continues working fine.

Is it possible that you dislodged the heatsink on the CPU? I've never opened my Macbook up, but I presume it has some sort of heatsink/heatpipe assembly to duct the heat towards the vents on the lid hinge. I'd check that was on correctly, and that the heat paste hadn't dried up (or that there isn't too much of it).

Then see if you can bodge the machine so it runs without being assembled and see what happens.

Comment: well i did have to take the heat sink out to replace the fan. however didn't think that was put in wrong. 

looks like i need to redo everything i did and make sure it's in there correctly

Answer (score 0):

I would have to say over heating.

Try removing and reinstalling the fan, but as for the question, I am 99% sure it is overheating.

Comment: Your fan was turning on for a very good reason! If your new one isn't as good, that could definately be the cause.

Comment: thanks. is it possible my Processor is going bad as well? confused why before i was getting 6krpm and still getting it. The solution to this is hiding from me.

Comment: The thermal control (extra pins) usually are there for a reason and only turn on when needed - if as you said, it happened when watching you tube - this is normal... higher cpu = higher heat = higher fan speeds.... I really wouldn't change from the one that was there before, if it goes wrong within 2 years, try going back to manufacturer saying it is faulty.

Comment: wow really? reason why i changed fan was it was making a horrible knocking sound. the fan i have now doesn't make knocking, but i guess i just installed wrong

Comment: Well, it should be loud-ish as in high speed, but if it is actually making a nocking noise, it could be off centre, a ball bearing could be ground down, or a blade could be bent.... so, a replacement could be needed after all - but, I would personally go with a like for like part - just make 100% sure that you replace the thermal grease / square as it is not effective without that.